# Show that $\neg$ and $\wedge$ form a functionally complete collection of logical operators

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that $\neg$ and $\wedge$ form a functionally complete collection of logical operators

Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. $p \vee q$ is equivalent to $\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$ and $p \to q$ is equivalent to $q \vee \neg p$.

Comment: So you use one of the De Morgan law to show that $p \vee q$ is equivalent to $\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$. But what about the second one you write?